# Do I have to pay an annual fee, simply to test/deploy my software on my own phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I cant see any way to get around this...

Comment: That's the same as developing for iOS, isn't it? I'm not a fan of that, either.

Comment: iOS you can't even do the development without the registration.  At least with WP7 you can develop and test in an emulator (or just play around).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are a student, no.  You can use [DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/default.aspx).  Otherwise, you have to be a registered developer to unlock the phone, which means paying the $99 fee.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are required to have a developer registration. Here is a good detailed [walkthrough](http://geekswithblogs.net/mbcrump/archive/2010/10/02/deploying-your-windows-phone-7-application-to-the-actual-hardware.aspx) on how to do it - assuming you have paid the fee. It is very similar to how you have to pay the annual fee to deploy to an iOS device also.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's the only way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Chevron WP7 to unlock your device to install applications that aren't on the Marketplace, like self-made apps.
http://www.chevronwp7.com/

Comment: The "Chevron WP7" project was canceled yesterday. You don't have this option anymore. The good news are that Microsoft intend to deliver an way to developers to test their applications without have to pay. http://migre.me/2EN7d