# Do I have to pay to develop for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Not a real programming question. However I find it related. If not, I'm sorry. :)

A friend of mine asked me to write a program for his Windows Phone 7.

I'm always up for a challenge so I told him I would.

However when searching the internet it looks like the application can only be installed when downloaded from the Microsoft App Hub.

So I tried to create a developer account there and I WTF´ed for a moment.

I have to pay $99.00 for a account.

Is this really the case? I'll give this program for free to my friend, so I cannot charge him $99.00 for the app ;)

Comment: You can develop using the Visual Studio Express version - which is free - but I haven't investigated the App Hub yet either.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty dumb, but still cheaper than what you have to pay to develop for iCrap.

Comment: I’m not familiar with “iCrap,” but if you are talking about Apple’s development tools, the fee is also $99.

Comment: @ChrisF Yay I can write an app for free. However the downside is that a have a app which I cannot install. I find that kinda useless... :D

Comment: @Nate I think that Kyle is refering to http://www.google.nl/imgres?imgurl=http://www.deviantart.com/download/80915728/Macintosh_iCrap_by_otas32.jpg&imgrefurl=http://otas32.deviantart.com/art/Macintosh-iCrap-80915728&h=900&w=1200&sz=305&tbnid=GF1FjbIs4DkOxM:&tbnh=113&tbnw=150&prev=/images%3Fq%3Dicrap&zoom=1&q=icrap&usg=__yUSsxdeSm8mrl5E8QlGMPAcABNs=&sa=X&ei=hP3_TJT1NMOu8gPopYSNCw&ved=0CCAQ9QEwAQ :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I have to pay an annual fee, simply to test/deploy my software on my own phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060116/do-i-have-to-pay-an-annual-fee-simply-to-test-deploy-my-software-on-my-own-phone)

Comment: @PeeHaa If I could give you +1 million for that I would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you do have to pay the fee :)

Comment: OMG That just sucks. Is there already a jailbreak for Windows Phone 7? :P

Comment: You probably can get it on to the device without paying the 99 but its probably time limited or something like the iPhone.  I had to buy an account for the xBox

Answer (score 7):

You can download free tools for development, but in order to install the result you have to either be a member of AppHub, or the person you're giving the app to has to be a member (a member can install up to 10 apps directly from xap files rather than downloading them).

There are free memberships for students, if that helps.

Comment: Not really. Don't really want to go back to school just to let my friend install the app. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: Convince your friend to go back to school.  Then he can get a free account and will be able to install your app.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the chevron unlocker from here:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=857127